# Why SIGKILL for oracle client does not leave stale session in server?

Tags: java, oracle, tcp

I'm experimenting with Oracle sessions and try to catch situations, when there is the stale session in database. I managed to do this after I switch off the network - database session is still alive and holds all locks, that were taken. That's clear: Oracle does not know, that TCP session is broken and still waits for requests.

But the other trial does not work: when I have the client connected and eventually kill it through "kill -9". I expect the same situation as in the previous example (stale session in Oracle as TCP connection is still working on server side) - but I see that session is cleared! As well as any locks. I cannot find out why - SIGKILL signal is expected to kill the process without any chance for it to launch any hooks like shutdown for TCP with "bye" message and so on. I suspect that OS (MacOs) frees any TCP sockets and sends end message on process kill, but this is only guess, I could not prove this in fact..

Who knows?

Comment: Are you asking this just to understand the internals or because you have an actual problem?  If you actually have an application that could potentially hold locks across client actions, you would almost certainly want to enable dead connection detection on the database so that Oracle can automatically terminate the session in the first case as well.

Comment: Both cases :) We eventually started to face the problems with connections from java app to Oracle - some locks hanged forever and connection pool ds went out of connections (dbcp). I tried to dive deeper into Oracle connections handling to find out possible reasons. Now I see that inconsistent network is the most possible reason for stale sessions. First we are going to change conn. pool and second - ask admins to enable dead connection detection. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system releases all unreleased resources of a process when it exits. That includes sockets, file descriptors, memory, semaphores, ... TCP will either reset or send a FIN on such a socket.

I would expect Oracle to time-out the sessions in the other situation you describe.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the TCP connection, Oracle process receives SIGHUP, rollbacks the active transaction (if any) and quits. If you kill Oracle session process(-9) the background process ("pmon") detects this a fires a new session which will be responsible for dead session's recovery(UNDO). Do not try this on production system - this is just to show how resilient Oracle is.

When you kill client process them it is OS who sends FIN packet to server a therefore Oracle knows then TCP connection is closed. This works on Unix and Linux but I have suspicion, that for some unknown reason this does not Work on Windows. (When VSphere dies, Oracle this sees dangling TCP connections even if Windows kernel is still running).

If you want to do some experiments with dead connection detection look the the option `enable=broken` in tnsnames.ora. Then set TCP Keepalive to some reasonable period (15 sec for eaxmple) and use tcpdump to want tcp keepalive packets sent by your clients kernel.
This is 100% transparent and does not require any kind of application's cooperation.

Comment: A process doesn't receive a `SIGHUP` as the result of a network event.

Comment: @EJP: if it's STDIN/STDOUT is redirected into the TCP socket, then yes.